# How to successfully destroy the process if it takes too much time in Java?

Tags: java, timeout, runtime, processbuilder

I am executing a shell script from my Java program using `Process` and I want to kill/destroy that process if my script takes long time. What is the best way to do this?

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // Your script
    String script = "#!/bin/bash\n\necho \"Hello World\"\n\n readonly PARAM1=$param1\n echo $PARAM1\n\nreadonly PARAM2=$param2\n echo $PARAM2\n\n";

    // create a temp file and write your script to it
    File tempScript = File.createTempFile("temp_scripts_", "");
    tempScript.setExecutable(true);
    try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempScript)) {
        output.write(script.getBytes());
    }

    // build the process object and start it
    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
    commandList.add(tempScript.getAbsolutePath());
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    builder.environment().put("param1", "abc");
    builder.environment().put("param2", "xyz");
    Process shell = builder.start();

    // read the output and show it
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shell.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    // wait for the process to finish
    // but I want to kill/destroy the process if it takes too much time
    int exitCode = shell.waitFor();

    // delete your temp file
    tempScript.delete();

    // check the exit code (exit code = 0 usually means "executed ok")
    System.out.println("EXIT CODE: " + exitCode);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE

The class `Process` doesn't have a "waitFor" method with a timeout unless you're using java 8. As an alternative, you can try starting a thread that waits for the process to finish and join such thread with `join(timeout)`.

The following is a proof of concept with your code, modified to work with a thread:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Your script
        String script = getScriptFromSomewhere();

        // create a temp file and write your script to it
        File tempScript = File.createTempFile("temp_scripts_", "");
        tempScript.setExecutable(true);
        try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempScript)) {
            output.write(script.getBytes());
        }

        // build the process object and start it
        List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
        commandList.add(tempScript.getAbsolutePath());
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.environment().put("param1", "abc");
        builder.environment().put("param2", "xyz");
        Process shell = builder.start();

        // Start the interrupting thread
        long timeoutMillis = 5000;
        ExecutingThread thread = new ExecutingThread(shell, timeoutMillis);
        thread.start();

        // read the output and show it
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try (InputStream input = shell.getInputStream()) {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                String text = new String(buffer, 0, read);
                System.out.print(text);
            }
        }

        // wait for the process to finish (or be interrupted)
        thread.join();

        if(!thread.isFinished()) {

            System.out.println("PROCESS WAS INTERRUPTED");

        } else {

            // check the exit code (exit code = 0 usually means "executed ok")
            System.out.println("PROCESS FINISHED, EXIT CODE: " + thread.getExitValue());

        }


        // delete your temp file
        tempScript.delete();
    }
}

class ExecutingThread extends Thread {

    private long timeoutMillis;
    private WaitingThread waitingThread;

    public ExecutingThread(Process shell, long timeoutMillis) {
        this.timeoutMillis = timeoutMillis;
        this.waitingThread = new WaitingThread(shell);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        waitingThread.start();
        try {
            waitingThread.join(timeoutMillis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
        if(waitingThread.isAlive()) {
            waitingThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    public int getExitValue() {
        return waitingThread.getExitValue();
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return waitingThread.isFinished();
    }

}


class WaitingThread extends Thread {

    private Process shell;
    private volatile int exitValue;
    private volatile boolean finished = false;

    public WaitingThread(Process shell) {
        this.shell = shell;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            exitValue = shell.waitFor();
            finished = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            shell.destroy();
        }
    }

    public int getExitValue() {
        return exitValue;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Quick question, why are you calling `shell.waitFor()` again after `shell.destroy()`? What is the reason we need this?

Comment: Actually you can skip this. The main reason is that calling `shell.destroy()` doesn't "destroy" the process immediately, so `waitFor()` is just to guarantee that your program is going to wait for the process to be totally terminated; but in your case I think it doesn't matter, so just delete that line.

Comment: hey don't you think reader.readLine() is a blocking operation and we have a timeout outside that? I am thinking it may fail. Still trying to get unix machine working as I had some issues  last night.

Comment: `readLine()` will throw an IOException at the moment the process is killed. Anyway, I changed the `BufferedReader` with a plain `InputStream` to print the output as soon as it is available and not to wait for it to complete a line. At last I was able to test this code at home, it works for both the happy path and the timeout

Comment: Have a try with a timeout of 5000, a "quick" script: `script = "#!/bin/bash\n\necho \"Hello World\"\n\n readonly PARAM1=$param1\n echo $PARAM1\n\nreadonly PARAM2=$param2\n echo $PARAM2\nfor x in {1..3}; do sleep 1; echo $x; done\n\n";` and a "slow" one: `script = "#!/bin/bash\n\necho \"Hello World\"\n\n readonly PARAM1=$param1\n echo $PARAM1\n\nreadonly PARAM2=$param2\n echo $PARAM2\nfor x in {1..20}; do sleep 1; echo $x; done\n\n";`

Comment: one more thing: I added more code, so copy/paste the entire code

Comment: sure, and we are not using `WaitingThread` class anymore right? Instead we are using `ExecutingThread`? Correct?

Comment: It is NOT correct, we are still using it, the code now uses two threads: one starts before we start reading the output and is the one which waits and interrupts the second one

Comment: aaahh just saw that.. make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = start + 60*1000; 
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: That will call the script over and over again every run.

Answer (score 0):

For what i see you are currently waiting infinitely long for a result, because

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

will block due to readline() being a blocking operation.

The naive approach would be to externalize the reading from the streams into an own thread, which you could interrupt at any time.

So basically you would have a thread object which in its constructor would get the appropriate streams and a common lockObject, and then in the run() method starts to try reading from the stream, and do whatever you wanna do with the data.

In your main thread, you could then, after starting the script and getting the wanted streams, construct such a thread instance and start it in its own thread. Then you would wait in your main thread for the second "reader" thread to finish (keyword here is wait(timeout), where timeout is the max (allowed) run time of your script.

So now your main thread is waiting for your reader thread to finish it's task, but at most for *timeout* milliseconds (or was it seconds?)
After that wait(timeout) you could then either kill the script (if it hangs, because your set timeout expired) or do whatever you want if it exited nicely.

I know there is no actual code included, but the approach should be valid.
Good luck